# Connection to mssql server using spring framework

Tags: sql-server, spring, jdbc

I am learning spring just now. I want to connect my webapp to a ms sql 2008 R2 server. but i am getting many errors doing so.
my bean file looks like this,

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://Mrunal-PC\\MSSQLSERVER1;DataBaseName=Test;" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="abc123" />
    </bean>
```

and i am getting following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1
\mssqlserver1
 ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:630)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:909)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:980)
    at com.tutorialspoint.StudentJDBCTemplate.create(StudentJDBCTemplate.java:19)
    at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:18)
```

erliear i was trying to connect using window authentication but even that time it was giving me time out error. I am really new here so i am unable to find any error. can anybody help me?

Comment: <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
  <property name="url"
   value="jdbc:sqlserver://Mrunal-PC\\MSSQLSERVER1;DataBaseName=Test;" />
  <property name="username" value="sa" />
  <property name="password" value="abc123" />
 </bean>

Comment: try ``\\\\`` instead

Comment: Thank you. i will try right away.

Comment: if i use \\\ then its giving me following error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the named instance  has failed. Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out.
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)

Comment: i tried many options but its not working. its still giving me time out error

Comment: Try the `localhost` instead of `Mrunal-PC`

Answer (score 1):

Try `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;DataBaseName=Test`.
See more on proper jdbc url at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: now its giving The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Is your server running on the default port? Is it running on the same machine you are running your Spring app?

Comment: it is running on the same machine. i enabled tcp connection in sql configuration manager and also mentioned the port as 1433 in ip section. its still not working

Comment: i tried to connect to my db using eclips ide but its not working. connection url is jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test